# Get all RFID readers connected to the network

Tags: c#, rfid, motorola, ws-discovery

I need to get all the `RFID` readers connected on the *ethernet*, currently I have an application which connects to one reader at a time. Also the *IP address* for the reader needs to be specified for connection.

I am using *Motorola FX9500* fixed `RFID` readers.
It supports DHCP, HTTPS, FTPS, SSH, HTTP, FTP, Telnet, SNMP and NTP, WS Discovery. I'm assigning a static IP to the reader from its configuration and the reader is connected to the LAN.

There's an application named *PowerSession* by *Motorola* in which the option to find all readers is present. Its tooltip says it discovers readers using `WS discovery/RDMP`.

Any idea regarding this approach?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a rather specific question, you should rephrase it a bit to get an answer. How do you communicate with them? TCP? UDP? Do they accept broadcast messages? The protocol most likely allows you to ping them, so a simple way might be to simply iterate through a range of IPs in your subnet. If they support UDP broadcasting, then it's even simpler.

Comment: It supports DHCP, HTTPS, FTPS, SSH, HTTP, FTP, Telnet, SNMP and NTP, WS Discovery. I'm assigning a static IP to the reader from its configuration and the reader is connected to the LAN.
There's an application named PowerSession by Motorola in which the option to find readers is present.
Its tooltip says it discovers readers using WS discovery/RDMP.
Any idea regarding this approach?

Answer (score 1):

WS Discovery is a scheme for using network multicast to interogate broad swatches of devices connected to a network.  In essence you are blinding communicating with everything on the network in a way to get responses back from specific devices.  Wikipedia has a simplified overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery

The RDMP part is a service definition for RFID Readers ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298713.aspx ). The idea being that using WS Discovery you might find all sorts of objects on the network that support web services but aren't necessarily RFID readers.  In the response you get back from each device will be definitions of what type of services the device supports.  In the case of these RFID readers, it should return RDMP content that effectively says, "Hey, I'm a RFID reader and here is some information about me."